# How to create new array items by grouping and merging the data each by certain property names?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, merge, grouping

I have this array of object

```
rows = [
    {
      id_temp: 1,
      description: 'template 1',
      color_id: 1,
      code: '#000000'

   },
    {
      id_temp: 1,
      description: 'template 1',
      color_id: 2,
      code: '#ffffff'

    },
   {
      id_temp: 2,
      description: 'template 2',
      color_id: 1,
      code: '#000000'

    },
   {
      id_temp: 2,
      description: 'template 2',
      color_id: 2,
      code: '#ffffff'

    },
]
```

i need to convert it to this shape, add color property as an array of objects that consists of the code and id from each iteration based on the repeated id_temp

```
[{
    "id_temp": 1,
    "description": "template 1",
    "color": [{
        "id": 1
        "code": "#000000"
         },
        {
        "id": 2
        "code": "#ffffff"
        }]
},
{
    "id_temp": 2,
    "description": "template 2",
    "color": [{
        "id": 1
        "code": "#000000"
    },
    {
      "id": 2
      "code": "#ffffff"
    }]
}]
```

i tried to loop through it in foreach but that leads to overwriting the values in the new array

```
let resultTemplates = [];
rows.forEach((row) => {
        if (resultTemplates[row.id_temp]) {
          resultTemplates['color'] = row.color_id;
          resultTemplates['color'] = row.code;
        } else {
          resultTemplates.id_temp = row.id_temp;
          resultTemplates.description = row.description;
          resultTemplates['color'].id = row.color_id;
          resultTemplates['color'].code = row.code;
        }
        });
```

Comment: The OP hereby gets notified that **1st)** the currently accepted implementation does not meet the OP's acceptance criteria for the expected result and **2nd)** there is a later provided second answer waiting for the OP's evaluation.

Comment: From all the provided answers / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Reduce` method

```js
const rows = [
    {
        id_temp: 1,
        description: "template 1",
        color_id: 1,
        code: "#000000",
    },
    {
        id_temp: 1,
        description: "template 1",
        color_id: 2,
        code: "#ffffff",
    },
    {
        id_temp: 2,
        description: "template 2",
        color_id: 1,
        code: "#000000",
    },
    {
        id_temp: 2,
        description: "template 2",
        color_id: 2,
        code: "#ffffff",
    },
];

const outArr = rows.reduce((acc, crt) => {
    if (!acc[crt.id_temp]) {
        crt["color"] = [
            {
                id: 1,
                code: crt.code,
            },
        ];
        acc[crt.id_temp] = crt;
    } else {
        acc[crt.id_temp].color.push({ id: acc[crt.id_temp].color.length +1, code: crt.code });
    }

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(outArr));
```

Comment: @AliAlmazawi ... actually, with the above approach, the data for color-id and -code are now duplicated for the first new `color` item within each new merged object.

Answer (score 0):

A lean (in terms of code and abstraction) `reduce` based implementation makes use of [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for both the function parameters and variable assignment(s) within the function body. It also does utilize the [rest property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property).

```
function groupCreateAndCollectNewItemsByTemplateId(
  index, { color_id, code, ...itemRest }
) {
  const { id_temp: groupKey } = itemRest;

  // ... more code ...
}
```

And in order to express the creation and/or access of a grouped item as well as the aggregation of an already created/grouped item one would choose the [Nullish Coalescing Assignment Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) / `??=`.

```
(index[groupKey] ??= { ...itemRest, color: [] })
```

The `index` is an object which gets aggregated programmatically by reducing the OP's `rows` array. It is the root object for the newly created grouped items where a `rows` item's `id_temp` value acts as the grouping key.

Within a final step the reduced intermediate grouping object needs to be passed to [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) in order to get an array of the grouping object's values which are the newly created template items.

```js
function groupCreateAndCollectNewItemsByTemplateId(
  index, { color_id, code, ...itemRest }
) {
  const { id_temp: groupKey } = itemRest;

  // create and/or access and aggregate a new grouped item.
  (index[groupKey] ??= { ...itemRest, color: [] })
    .color
    .push({ id: color_id, code });

  return index;
}

const rows = [{
  id_temp: 1,
  description: 'template 1',
  color_id: 1,
  code: '#000000',
}, {
  id_temp: 1,
  description: 'template 1',
  color_id: 2,
  code: '#ffffff',
}, {
  id_temp: 2,
  description: 'template 2',
  color_id: 1,
  code: '#000000',
}, {
  id_temp: 2,
  description: 'template 2',
  color_id: 2,
  code: '#ffffff',
}];

console.log(
  'the expected result ...',
  Object.values(
    rows.reduce(groupCreateAndCollectNewItemsByTemplateId, {})
  ),
);
console.log(
  'the grouped index/map as intermediate result ...',
  rows.reduce(groupCreateAndCollectNewItemsByTemplateId, {})
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```